# How to recalibrate do different mean value

Tags: r, regression

I would like to refit and obtain new estimates such that the latest model fit (shorter sample 50 obs in this example) is re-calibrated by taking into account the long term mean. So how to perform the intercept (slope?) shift?

Here is some data:

```
set.seed(2017); n <- 200; price <- rep(55, n); walk <- rnorm(n)
for(i in 2:n) price[i] <- price[i-1] + walk[i]; 
data <- data.frame(price, idx=seq_along(price))
```

The model part:

```
# mean of price on whole data set: 55.03

plot(price ~ idx, data=data)
abline(lm(price ~ 1, data=data), col="red", lwd=2)

# here the mean on reduced sample is 52.85: 
# lm(price ~ 1, data=data[((nrow(data)-50):nrow(data)), ])
abline(lm(price ~ idx, data=data[((nrow(data)-50):nrow(data)), ]));
```

So how to adapt the fit of `lm(price ~ idx, data=data[((nrow(data)-50):nrow(data)), ])`; so that it reflects the `long term mean` of the whole data set. (without having to re-run the regression on whole dataset.)

Example:

```
fit <- lm(price ~ idx, data=data[((nrow(data)-50):nrow(data)), ])
fit

predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(idx=200)) 
# mean value 56.71, needed `long-term mean` of 55.03 (circa)
```